# The polygon width parallel to the x axis as a function of the y ordonate?

Tags: integration, polynomials, polygons

Considering a polygon with n vertices as input.

[image]

I need to calculate the integral of the form
\[\int_A p(y) dA \] where $p(y)$ is a piecewise polynomial function of $y$.

May be if I could find  the expression $b(y)$ then the integral can be calculated by:
$$\int_{0}^{y_\max} p(y) b(y) dy $$

The question is : "is there a straightforward method to find $b(y)$ given the coordinates of the polygon vertices? Or is there a simpler manner to calculate the integral above?"

Comment: Try looking into [Green’s theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

I posted a comment about Green's Theorem earlier, but since nobody has answered this question so far, I figured I might as well write one up. Green's Theorem states:

$$\oint_C P\ dx+Q\ dy=\iint_A\left(\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)dA$$

In the context of this problem, $C$ denotes the boundary of the polygon and $A$ denotes the interior of the polygon. Obviously, $C$ is piecewise smooth, simple, and closed, and so we can invoke Green's Theorem (we do have to be careful with the orientation).

As you stated, we need to calculate the integral

$$\iint_A p(y)\ dA$$

where $p(y)$ is a polynomial. Let $P(x, y)=-\int_0^yp(t)\ dt$ and $Q(x, y)$ be constant (note that $P$ just has to be the negative of any antiderivative of $p$, I chose one arbitrarily). Then, it follows that

$$\left(\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)=p(y)$$

From here, we can equate

$$\iint_Ap(y)\ dA=\oint_CP\ dx$$

and compute the line integral. The rest should be straightforward.

Comment: Thank you @doobdood. So  for a 3 order polynomial $p(y)$, $P(y)$ will be a  polynomial of order 4 . So is there an efficient way to calculate $\oint_C P dx$ in this case .

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda I'm sure there are simplifications you can make to the closed line integral. I haven't worked it out yet, but you'd be parameterising $x$ as a linear function of $y$ to connect adjacent vertices, e.g. $y=-3+5x$ or something.